# Calculating a similarity score based on both nominal and scale variables

Tags: spss, conjoint-analysis

I'm currently writing my master thesis on the importance of deep-level similarities between a mentor and mentee for the mentorship effectiveness.

In order to test this, I've had 5 respondents evaluate 8 mentee profiles each to indicate their expected mentorship effectiveness on a scale of 1 to 7.

My main problem lies in calculating a similarity score as the independent variable. This is because the similarity between the respondent and the mentee profile is based on 6 variables: 5 personality characterstics and one cognitive style characterstic.

The personality characterstics are measured on an interval scale for the respondents and on a nominal scale for the mentee profiles (either 'high' or 'low')

The cognitive style characteristic is measured on an nominal scale for both the respondent and the mentee profile ('thinking' or 'feeling').

*Do you have advice for me on how to calculate a similarity score?*

Comment: Since your task is to compute a similarity between two objects (a mentor and a mentee) you must have the same attributes and measured in the same units, for both. Since, unfortunately, you have only 2-categorical scale for personality attributes in mentees you'll have to categorize that for mentors likewise, too. After that, you are left with all of attributes binary. There are plenty of similarity measures for binary data, to select from.